# How to create opacity effect on webOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webos

I have an html video element in my page :

```
<video id="myVideo" src = "./play.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

I am making it disappear on some action like this :

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

I can make it appear back again with

```
vid.style.visibility = "visible";
```

But I want the video to ease in smoothly how can I do this via javascript ?

I tried :

```
vid.style.transition   = "visibility 2s";
vid.style.visibility = "visible";
```

But it didn't work. Could anyone point my mistake ?  (The webOS platform doesn't support jquery and the [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) css property)

> I cannot use opacity  :( --> Developer documentation : The opacity property is unapplicable on video elements.

Comment: Can you describe the "platform" ?

Comment: Its the webOS platform I added it as well :)

Comment: You can use jQuery on webOS, but that won't fix the opacity issue (if that is the issue).

Comment: @Pre101 you are absolutely correct. I found out I can't use opacity only after using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css transition and rgba format with some javascript to add opacity animation without the css opacity property.

```js
var hide = document.getElementById('tryh'),
    show = document.getElementById('trys'),
    foo  = document.getElementById('foo');

show.addEventListener('click', function () {
  foo.className = 'foo show';
});

hide.addEventListener('click', function () {
  foo.className = 'foo hide';
});
```

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.hide {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.show {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.foo:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div id='foo' class='foo'>
  <video id="video" src="./play.mp4" controls autoplay loop ></video>
</div>

<button id='trys'>Show</button>
<button id='tryh'>Hide</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Although this is working on the browser, I just saw on the webOS platform opacity cannot be applied. My mistake. I just learnt this. I updated the question.

Comment: @PavanK I add a way with rgba format. You can try it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. Unfortunately, this didn't work again. I think this is related to opacity indirectly through the alpha channel. But i ll accept your answer for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery fadeToggle function: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

```
$('#myVideo').fadeToggle();
```

For example if you have a button for hiding and showing with an id of 'toggleBtn':

```
$('#toggleBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#myVideo').fadeToggle();
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98z8wLfL/

Comment: Thank you so much but the platform I am working on doesn't support jquery unfortunately.

Comment: @rodes, the OP's question is about JavaScript, not jquery. See question and tags

Answer (score 0):

Seem slike adding a background with any color to the `video` tag  makes the `transition` work.

Here is an [**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/adJqEe) you can see i've only added `background:#000` to the video tag in the css stylesheet (ex. this is not needed with a `div` tag).

CSS:

```
#myVideo {
  background:#000;
}
```

JS:

```
var vid = document.querySelector('#myVideo');
vid.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in";

vid.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  e.target.style.opacity = 0;
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Although this is working on the browser, I just saw on the webOS platform opacity cannot be applied. My mistake. I just learnt this. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `visibility` is not animatable, nor transitionable.

If you really need to switch it, you can do so thanks to the `transitionend` event.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.style.opacity = "1";

// set it only once or in your css
vid.style.transition = "opacity 2s";

btn.onclick = function() {
    if (this.style.visibility !== 'visible') {
      vid.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    vid.style.opacity = +!+vid.style.opacity;
  }
  // use the transitionend if you need to
vid.ontransitionend = function() {
  if (this.style.visibility === 'visible') {
    this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" src="./play.mp4" controls autoplay loop></video>

<button id="btn">show/hide</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Although this is working on the browser, I just saw on the webOS platform opacity cannot be applied. My mistake. I just learnt this. I updated the question